# Unix directory permissions for write

Tags: unix, permissions

Say I have a folder "root". I own this folder, and I make it such that for others (which includes the user "user2", the permissions are r-x)

Within root I have another folder "bin". I change the owner of "bin" to the user "user2", and give him rwx permissions.

1. Will user2 be able to create new files in the folder "bin"? Does not having write for "root" affect his ability to do so?
2. Also, can user2 delete the entire folder "bin" from "root"? (I don't want him to be able to do so - he just needs to create/delete files within the folder bin!)

Comment: This should be pretty easy to try for yourself... Create a test directory and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes.  Because `user2` has access (`x`) permission on `root` and owns `bin`, he can create files in `root/bin`.  If the permissions do not currently include write permission for the owner, the owner (`user2`) can change the directory permissions so that the permissions do include write permission.
2. No.  Because `user2` does not have write permission in `root`, `user2` cannot remove `bin` from `root`.

Answer (score 2):

He can write inside of bin, but not outside of it. The scope of his rwx permissions resides within that folder unless you otherwise modify his permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding what you stated you have something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  10 root     root          22 Dec 26 23:04 root
```

where the contents of "root" are like this:

```
cd root
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  10 root     root          22 Dec 26 23:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  29 root     root          34 Oct 24 06:13 ..
drwx------   2 user2    root           3 Oct 23 10:28 bin
```

The permissions on "root" have to be at least 555 (r-xr-xr-x) because it would not work if your "root" directory permissions were 500 or 550 (see below) because "user2" would not be allowed to enter the directory "root" (there are exceptions, like 550 would work if "user2" is member of the "root" group).

```
# This would not work, user2 cannot enter the "root" directory
drwx------  10 root     root          22 Dec 26 23:04 root
```

To understand all this security stuff you first have to realize that a directory is really, and simply, a file. The major difference between a directory and a file is the meaning of the "x" permission. If the user does not have "read" permission, he can't see the files in the directory. So, lets put the access to 711, like this:

```
drwx--x--x  10 root     root          22 Dec 26 23:04 root
```

Now let's try to see what files are in the directory. You can't:

```
$ ls -la root
root: Permission denied
total 3
```

However, you can enter it (because of the "x" execute right) but you still can not see inside:

```
$ cd root
$ ls -la
.: Permission denied
total 3
```

But if you are aware that inside there exists a directory you have access to, you can enter it:

```
$ cd bin  # Ps. Here we assume we did the 'cd root' above already
$ ls -la
total 6
drwxr-xr-x   2 user2    root           2 Mar 14 14:57 .
drwx--x--x   3 root     root           3 Mar 14 14:57 ..
```

And "user2" can do, as the owner, anything he wants. The access to "bin" could even be "700", as long as you are the owner, you can enter it. Because the access is 755 (in our example), anyone can enter the directory "bin", but only "user2" can create files in it. Modifying or reading those possible files will depend on the access "user2" gives them.

"user2" cannot remove the "bin" directory, even if he owns it, because he does not own the "file" (i.e. the "root" directory) where the name of the "bin" directory is written. That is owned by the "root" user who is the only one allowed to write there.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the detailed explanation with examples! :)